# Need help finding a "tr" tag with a nested "th" tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a code snippet for use with the [TASVideos TAS submission finder](http://www.tasvideos.org). This snippet will add a "td" tag to the beginning of each list entry, so people who are fast readers (and even people who aren't, since I'm using 3 letter codes) can quickly find TASVideos.org approved TAS's and look at them, or any other TAS they want. I would like to have 2 modes (System and Status). I was working on the Status portion and had an error. Here is my code.

```
wikitable = document.getElementsByClassName("wikitable")[0];
wikitableTR = wikitable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var tr;
QuickScrubHeader = document.createElement("th")
QSHText = document.createTextNode("QuickScrub for TAS Videos")
QuickScrubHeader.appendChild(QSHText)
wikitableTR.getElementsByTagName("th")[0].insertBefore(QuickScrubHeader)
for (var tr in wikitableTR){
    delete addend, addendText;
    td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
    addend = document.createElement("td")
    if(td[3].innerhtml == "published");{
        addendText = document.createTextNode("PUB")
        addend.appendChild(addendText)
        tr.insertBefore(addend)
    }
}
```

The sloppy block of code is this:

```
QuickScrubHeader = document.createElement("th")
QSHText = document.createTextNode("QuickScrub for TAS Videos")
QuickScrubHeader.appendChild(QSHText)
wikitableTR.getElementsByTagName("th")[0].insertBefore(QuickScrubHeader)
```

I would like to know how to make that last line of the sloppy code work so that it finds the "tr" tag with the "th" tags inside, and puts my `QuickScrubHeader` element before the other elements, much like how the for/in loop I have looks for a certain value in `td[3]` and inserts a special "td" tag at the beginning of the list.

Comment: use `innerHTML` not `innerhtml` . Also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore (2 arguments are expected)

Comment: OK, thank you. Yet, this still doesn't answer my original question. I wanted to know how to find the "tr" tag that had the "th" tags in it and append a special header. I didn't need help on **capitalization**, but thanks.

Comment: It looks like `QuickScrubHeader` should be `var quickScrubHeader`, unless you're trying to clobber a constructor that's already been defined on `window`. (Likewise for `QSHText`.)

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley I use the `varname = value` instead of `var varname = value` so that I can (eventually) delete those variables from memory. Globals, afaik, cannot be deleted as easily as window vars (which, btw, delete as simple as `delete varname`)

Comment: You've got it backwards. `var` is only "global" when used in the global scope. "Window vars" *are* global vars (go ahead, open the console and try it: `var foo = 'bar'; console.log(window.foo)` will print `bar`), and that's what you're making when you use an unqualified declaration (which, btw, is an *error* in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

Comment: On top of that, your variables should be created (using `var`) within the context of a function (at the very least an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)): if there are any unreferenced values lingering after the execution of the function, they will be "deleted from memory" as part of [garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection) - no "`delete varname`" necessary.

Comment: *Besides* that, the convention in JavaScript (and other C-derived languages like [Go](https://golang.org/)) is to only capitalize [constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Constructor) (which is why that have special coloring in StackOverflow's syntax highlighting). This is why the variables should be named `quickScrubHeader` and `qshText`.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Ok. I was just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```
var th_list = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable > tr > th');
th_list[0].parentNode.insertBefore(QuickScrubHeader,th_list[0]);
```